# How to select Parent's sibling in SCSS?

Tags: sass

How to select Parent's sibling in SCSS? I have the following html. I need to select label with text apply class?

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label class="a">A</label>
  </div>
  <label>apply class</label> 
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <label class="b">B</label>
  </div>
  <label>don't apply class</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use next selector: div > div + label {
  ...
}

Comment: I have to select label which is  sibling of div containing child label with class a

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS. You have to find a different way.